# Using Spotfire functions when connecting to a Database connection

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I'm connecting my Spotfire to Postgres database. After connecting to the db some of the functions are not available in Spotfire. I want to know if there is a way I can be connected to the database and still use all the Spotfire functionalities. I have huge amount of data and I need to store it in a database as using Excel is not a viable solution. I understand when I connect to a database I can only use limited functions supported by the database. I wanted to know there is a way around this situation.

If there is a workaround like similar to qvd's in qlik or if I can store data in another dxp file and use that to import data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not because of external data, I spoke to Spotfire support they don't support this, if I'm connecting to a database, I'll only be able to use limited functions. I found an alternative solution though using information links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you kept your data external, and that's why you can't use some Spotfire functionalities.

To have your data embedded, just select this option when you add a datatable. In the load method, select "import data" instead of "keep data external".

If you have too much data in your database, consider using the "load on demand" functionality to only get the data you want.